# How to get an ordered set in OCL?

Tags: unordered-set, ocl

When I have a result of type **`Set(Integer)`**, numbers are not ordered.  We have an operation usable on collections called **`sortedBy ( expr : OclExpression ) : Sequence(T)`**, but when there's only integers in this set, what's the expression to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the asOrderedSet operation (if your collection is in the variable X, then that would be X->asOrderedSet())

From the OCL Standard
asOrderedSet() : OrderedSet(T)
An OrderedSet that contains all the elements from self, with duplicates removed, in an order dependent on the particular
concrete collection type.